# Which are the advantadges of adding a use clause for a unit in the implementation section?

Tags: delphi

If I put a unit in the uses clause of the implementation section of a unit, the identifiers declared in such unit are not available to the interface section.

What is the advantage of doing that and not being able to use identifiers from the referred unit in the interface?

Is there any practical advantage (such as avoiding unwanted side effects) if you bother to add used units in the implementation section instead of simply doing it the interface section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest issue is that uses in the interface section can lead to circular dependencies and compilation failure. If unit A uses unit B in the interface section, then unit B cannot use unit A in its interface section.

So, you are often forced into putting at least some uses into the implementation section.

Otherwise I personally prefer to put unit uses into the interface section if at all possible. The main reason being one of scoping and hiding. If there are name scoping clashes (two units define the same name, and the second use hides the first) then rather the same name was in scope throughout the entire unit.

Comment: I use the opposite approach in very large codebases, though I doubt it matters in small ones; Minimize size of Interface uses clause. Keeps namespaces less polluted.

Comment: Developers also tend to put as many units as possible in the `implementation` area which are not necessary for the `interface`, such as `StrUtils` and `Math`, although that doesn't necessarily make any effect.

Comment: Putting unit X in the interface uses of unit A, makes it easier for types and methods of unit X to be used in the (type) declarations of unit A. Too easy in my opinion. I prefer having as little as possible in the interface uses clause because using stuff from X in the interface section of unit A, increases coupling and I want that to be conscious decision. Adding unit X or having to move X from the implementation to the interface uses clause is such a conscious act.

Comment: Actually uses in the interface section do not lead to circular dependencies, they prevent them (through that compiler error). In my opinion it is a bad move to put everything in the interface just to be alerted to circular dependencies. As in my previous comment, it puts too much in scope for the interface declarations and that tends to get used "just because it already is in scope" without a conscious evaluation of whether you want that extra coupling on the interface level.

Comment: @MarjanVenema That's reasonable. But it's not one way traffic. Using units in the implementation makes for coupling too. In fact that's what you allude to in your second comment. It would be so much better if the language had better support for modularisation.

Comment: Yep I would like more support for modularisation too. For now I make do with what Interface has to offer... I even have more and more type declarations in the implementation section. Nice way to ensure that stuff only gets out through the IInterface derived stuff. And also helps put a cap on unit testing going hay wire. Any type declared in an implementation section doesn't need its own unit tests, but is tested through the implementer (of an interface) that uses it.

Answer (score 13):

Adding a unit to the `uses` clause of the `implementation` section allows that unit to be a private dependency only to the `implementation`, not to the `interface`.  If UnitA uses UnitB, but no one outside of UnitA cares whether UnitA uses UnitB, because UnitA's interface does not use UnitB, then why advertise the dependency and clutter the `interface`?  Also, if you ever need to remove UnitB and/or replace it with something else, declaring it in the `uses` clause of the `implementation` section avoids an `interface` change that would affect any unit that is using UnitA.

Comment: +1 Good advice to avoid any "temptation" of circular references unless needed. Such a clear/mandatory/syntax-driven distinction between interface and implementation is something I like very much in Delphi, and lack in Java or C#.

Comment: @Arnaud Putting uses in the implementation section makes it easy to introduce circular references. There's a clear distinction between interface and implementation in C# and Java.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was not talking about `interface` and `class` keyword distinction. "There's a clear distinction between interface and implementation in C# and Java"... thanks to the IDE folding abilities? Or to the public/private/protected attributes? IMHO it is not as clear as the `interface...implementation` sections in pascal.